# IndexOf returns -1 when it should return 0

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm having a weird problem with the `IndexOf` function:

```
"strcat".IndexOf("st")
```

returned **-1**

```
"strcat".IndexOf("str")
```

returned **0**

Can anyone explain why that happened?

Comment: Can't reproduce this.

Comment: That (probably) didn't actually happen...have another look at your assumptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may be related to your system's current culture. Based on your name, I assumed Vietnamese.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New Globalization.CultureInfo("vi-VN")
Dim i1 As Int32 = "strcat".IndexOf("st")
Dim i2 As Int32 = "strcat".IndexOf("str")
Dim i3 As Int32 = "strcat".IndexOf("st", System.StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
Dim i4 As Int32 = "strcat".IndexOf("str", System.StringComparison.InvariantCulture)
```

yields: i1 = -1, i2 = 0, i3 = 0, i4 = 0

---

Edited to this address question posed in the comments section.

> How does this happen? I don't see anything the culture would change?

To answer this you should refer to the documentation for the method.
see:  [String.IndexOf Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

The relevant information is:

> This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) search using the current culture. The search begins at the first character position of this instance and continues until the last character position.

A given culture has its own rules for what is considered "common knowledge/pratice".  You should not assume that what you consider normal is normal in a different culture.  This is reason that the methods that perform comparisons allow you to specify a culture to define the rules used to perform the comparison.

This does not apply only to strings, but also dates.

The most famous programming conundrum is:  Does your program pass the **turkey test**?  Also known as the "Turkish-I problem".  These are terms that you can research for more information.

Comment: How does this happen? I don't see anything the culture would change?

Comment: @Sam, please see modified answer.

Comment: Thanks for the revision. I guess from an ASCII point of view, what is the difference between ST in the two cultures? What does the Singapore culture do differently?